# rsync code will run, but not in cron

Tags: cron, backup, rsync

I have a web server (odin) and a backup server (jofur). On jofur, I can run the following code to rsync my web directories (via key authentication) from odin to jofur:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin
```

If I enter this into the command line, everything rsyncs perfectly:

```
myuser@jofur:~$ rsync -avz -e ssh backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin

receiving incremental file list

sent 23 bytes  received 1921 bytes  1296.00 bytes/sec
total size is 349557271  speedup is 179813.41
```

I want this to run every morning, so I edited my crontab to read this:

```
0 4 * * * rsync -avz -e ssh backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin
```

This doesn't work. The following message is deposited in /var/mail/myuser:

> Could not create directory '/home/myuser/.ssh'.
>   Host key verification failed.
>   rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
>   rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]

I'm not sure what this error means. I'm wary of futzing blindly with permissions because I don't want to leave any backdoors open. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to tell whether cron is using the wrong rsync binary or whether rsync requires some variable which is not being set in cron. Please set the stdout/stderr as shown below and pass on the output of the log file

Also, try doing a "which rsync" from the command line ; this will tell you which rsync you are using from the command line.

```
0 4 * * * rsync -avz -e ssh backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin > /tmp/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

EDIT :

Can you create a shell script called SOME_DIR/cron_job_rsync.sh which contains the following. Make sure you set the execute bit.

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/rsync -avz -e ssh backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin
```

And modify the cronjob as shown below

```
0 4 * * * SOME_DIR/cron_job_rsync.sh >/tmp/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Hi Kevin - 

"which rsync" returns: 

`/usr/bin/rsync`

But when I add this to the end of my cron command: 

`> /tmp/cron_output.log 2>&1`

crontab fails to run at all, even when set to run every minute. I know this because when I set it to run every minute (* * * * * *) it will throw errors to mail, but if I put your code in, it doesn't throw any errors, nor does it update the output log.

Comment: Hi Kevin - sorry for the delay. Here's what cron_output.log says: `/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/scripts/cron_rsync.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: Make sure the execution bit is set for "cron_rysnc.sh". Also, the first line needs to be "#!/bin/sh"

Comment: Hi Kevin - I was missing the exclamation point. Once I did that, the log file read `/home/user/scripts/cron_rsync.sh: 2: /home/user/scripts/cron_rsync.sh: /usr/sbin/rsync: not found.` Indeed, there was no rsync under /usr/sbin/, but there was under /usr/bin, so I modified cron_rsync.sh to read `#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e ssh backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/user/mydomain.` Now the log reads `receiving incremental file list sent 23 bytes  received 2368 bytes  4782.00 bytes/sec
total size is 497303674  speedup is 207989.83.` Does this mean it's working?

Comment: If the output matches what you see on the command line then yes. But please confirm by checking the file on the target server.

Comment: This is odd - it didn't transfer at 4 AM. So I checked the output log and it read `/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/scripts/cron_rsync.sh: not found.`But that's definitely where cron_rsync.sh is, the execution bit is definitely set, and if I copy/paste the code in cron_rsync.sh to the command line then rsync definitely runs correctly.

Comment: From the command line execute /home/user/scripts/cron_rsync.sh

Comment: I did; it runs perfectly: `user@jofur: /home/user/scripts/cron_rsync.sh 
receiving incremental file list
backups/www/
backups/www/www-2013-01-11-06-51.tgz

sent 70 bytes  received 12598479 bytes  3599585.43 bytes/sec
total size is 521668061  speedup is 41.41`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Mine was the HOME directory was encrypted.

If your user is logged, it works the known_hosts.

But when it's a cron, the cron uses the right user BUT it does not have access to your $HOME/~/.ssh directory because is encrypted :-(

Comment: This isn't an answer, more a comment.  Where is your solution?

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error just like you.

I finally found user home directory is an 'mount point', when logged in, it changed.

You can use the shell command 'mount' to check if you have the same way to use home directory.

So, i logged in and 'cd /', then do

```

```
cp -ar ${HOME}/.ssh /tmp/
sudo umount ${HOME}
mv /tmp/.ssh ${HOME}
```

```

There is may failed, because you need to check the ${HOME} if you have the right to write, if not, try sudo or add writable to ${HOME}.

After that, every thing being fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using the correct *keyring* solved the issue for me. Add the following line to your crontab:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

In total, your crontab (edited by calling `crontab -e` from your terminal) should now look as follows:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
0 4 * * * rsync -avz backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin
```

**Background:** It turns out that some Linux distributions use a keyring to protect your public-private key pair - so the key pair is password-protected without ever noticing you. Consequently, `rsync` is not able to open your ssh key for authentication.

Note that I also omitted the `-e ssh`; I think it is not necessary here.

**Further Troubleshooting:** `rsync` does not provide a lot of debugging output. What helped me identify the problem was to put a dummy `scp` command, which is much more verbose, in my crontab. A crontab entry for troubleshooting may look something like:

```
* * * * * scp -v backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups/dummy.txt /home/myuser/odin/dummy.txt >> /home/myuser/odin/dummy.txt.log 2>&1
```

The above command will run every minute (great for developing) and it will copy a file `/home/backups/dummy.txt` to your local machine. All logs (stdout and stderr) are written to to `/home/myuser/odin/dummy.txt.log`. Inspect these logs to see where the error precisely comes from.

**Reference:** The troubleshooting explained above lead me to the solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332353/395749

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to avoid the error
http://umasarath52.blogspot.in/2013/09/solved-rsync-not-executing-via-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by communicating with the administrators for my server.  Here is what they told me:

> For advanced security and performance, we use 1H (Hive) which
>   utilizes a chrooted environment for users. Libraries and binaries
>   should be copied to the chrooted environment to make them accessible.

They sent me a follow up email telling me that the "Relevent" packages have been installed. At that point, the problem was resolved.  Unfortunately, I didn't get any additional information from them.  The host was Arvixe, but I'm guessing that anyone using 1H (Hive) will encounter a similar problem. Hopefully this answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rrsync` script together with a dedicated ssh key as follows:

REMOTE server

```
mkdir ~/bin
gunzip /usr/share/doc/rsync/scripts/rrsync.gz -c > ~/bin/rrsync
chmod +x ~/bin/rrsync
```

LOCAL computer

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_remote_backup -C "Automated remote backup"      #NO passphrase
scp ~/.ssh/id_remote_backup.pub devel@10.10.10.83:/home/devel/.ssh
```

REMOTE computer

```
cat id_remote_backup.pub >> authorized_keys
```

Prepend to the newly added line the following

```
command="$HOME/bin/rrsync -ro ~/backups/",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding
```

So that the result looks like

```
command="$HOME/bin/rrsync -ro ~/backups/",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAA...vp Automated remote backup
```

LOCAL

Put in your `crontab` the following script with `x` permission:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ""
echo ""
echo "CRON:" `date`
set -xv
rsync -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_remote_backup" -avzP devel@10.10.10.83:/ /home/user/servidor
```

Source: http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/01/14/restricting-ssh-access-to-rsync/

Answer (score 0):

I did several steps to make it work.

1. Check your paths. For every command you'll use check `which [command]` and use that full path for the crontab
2. Open crontab as the user you want to run it with so it has access to that users ssh-key
3. Add (remember to user which) `ssh-agent && [your ssh-command]` so it can connect over ssh.
4. When authentication still fails at this point. Try to generate a passwordless ssh-key. This way you can skip the password prompting.

For debugging it is useful to add -vvv to the ssh command in rsync. It makes it clear what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, when using Crontab to run any script, ensure the script's path is full.
Don't Assume The Crontab will locate the script, keep the habit of always using an absolute path to your scripts and files also

**For Example**

DON'T do this:

```bash
0 4 * * * rsync -avz -e ssh backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin
```

**Do this instead (Notice rsync in full path */usr/bin/rsync*, and *-e* has the private key inside a string):**

```bash
0 4 * * * /usr/bin/rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /home/myuser/.ssh/private-key" backups@odin.mydomain.net:/home/backups /home/myuser/odin
```

> NOTE: Make sure the remote destination host has the public key in the appropriate location. 
> i.e., Make sure to have set up SSH public key authentication correctly [Check the link to set up SSH keys](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews)